# Why is SelectionChange event at the application level not working?

Tags: vba, excel, excel-addins

I have created a little macro to return the number of unique values and display it in the status bar of Excel when a range is selected. This works fine at the document level. However the `SelectionChange` event is not launching when I attempt to run it at the application level. The following is what I have.

**Class Module 'ExcelEventCapture'**

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents ExcelApp As Application

Private Sub ExcelApp_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If TypeName(Target) = "Range" Then
        Application.StatusBar = "Unique Count: " & CountUnique(Target)
    End If
End Sub

Private Function CountUnique(rng As Range) As Long
        Dim dict As Dictionary
        Dim cell As Range
        Set dict = New Dictionary
        For Each cell In rng.Cells
            If cell.Value2 <> 0 Then
                If Not dict.Exists(cell.Value) Then
                    dict.Add cell.Value, 0
                End If
            End If
        Next
        CountUnique = dict.Count
End Function
```

**ThisWorkbook**

```
Option Explicit

Dim myobject As New ExcelEventCapture

Sub Workbook_Open()
    Set myobject.ExcelApp = Application
End Sub
```

What am I missing? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SelectionChange` event does not exist in [Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn254092.aspx) class.

You can use [SheetSelectionChange](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839035.aspx) event and there is no need to check `Target` class name.

```
Private Sub ExcelApp_SheetSelectionChange(ByVal Sh As Object, ByVal Target As Range)    
    Application.StatusBar = "Unique Count: " & CountUnique(Target)
End Sub
```